# expressionengine write query using the database class

Tags: expressionengine

How do i rewrite this query portion in an expressionengine plugin

```
$query = "UPDATE {$table} SET ";
foreach ($original_record as $key => $value) {
    if ($key != $id_field) {
        $query .= '`'.$key.'` = "'.str_replace('"','\"',$value).'", ';
    }
} 
$query = substr($query,0,strlen($query)-2); # lop off the extra trailing comma
$query .= " WHERE {$id_field}={$newid}";
mysql_query($query);
```

I tried the following but it's giving me an error unexpected `;` on the first line

```
$query = $this->EE->db->query("UPDATE exp_channel_titles SET ";
foreach ($original_record1 as $key => $value) {
    if ($key != $id_field) {
        $query .= '`'.$key.'` = "'.str_replace('"','\"',$value).'", ';
    }
}
$query = substr($query,0,strlen($query)-2); # lop off the extra trailing comma
$query .= "WHERE entry_id={$newid}");
mysql_query($query); // Is this needed or should i remove it.
```

Answer (score 2):

Using EE built in functions (much simpler and easier to read):

```
$this->EE =& get_instance();

$query = array();
foreach ($original_record as $key => $value) {
    if ($key != $id_field) {
        $query[$key] = str_replace('"','\"',$value);
    }
} 
$this->EE->db->where('entry_id', $newid);
$this->EE->db->update($table, $query);
```

But to explain why your code doesn't work;

```
$this->EE->db->query
```

This is an EE function to run the query, so your query needs to be built as a string prior to passing it to this. so...

```
$query = "UPDATE exp_channel_titles SET ";
foreach ($original_record1 as $key => $value) {
    if ($key != $id_field) {
        $query .= '`'.$key.'` = "'.str_replace('"','\"',$value).'", ';
    }
}
$query = substr($query,0,strlen($query)-2); # lop off the extra trailing comma
$query = " WHERE entry_id={$newid}";
$queryResults = $this->EE->db->query($query);
```

Comment: And you might want to convert the results to an array afterwards:
`$result = $queryResults->result_array();`